# Change radio input value on click ( change it back actually )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Change radio input selection on on click on selectx2 div:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="inputoptions">
                            <span><input type="radio" name="abc" value="x1" checked="checked" class="y1" /> x1</span>
                            <span><input type="radio" name="abc" value="x2" class="y2" /> x2</span>
                            <span><input type="radio" name="abc" value="x3" class="y3" /> x3</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="selectx2">select x2</div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript to change/select x2:

```
$('.selectx2').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.box').children('.inputoptions').children('.y2').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) it find the immediate child of element and `y2` is not immediate child of `inputoptions`.

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Use

```
    $(this)
     .closest('.box')
     .children('.inputoptions')
     .find('.y2') //Use find here instead of children
     .prop('checked', true);
```

OR

```
 $(this)
     .closest('.box')
     .find('.inputoptions .y2')
     .prop('checked', true);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectx2').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.box').find('.inputoptions .y2').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="inputoptions">
      <span><input type="radio" name="abc" value="x1" checked="checked" class="y1" /> x1</span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="abc" value="x2" class="y2" /> x2</span>
      <span><input type="radio" name="abc" value="x3" class="y3" /> x3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="selectx2">select x2</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```